# PowerShell - Import Excel then Export CSV without using Excel or COM

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I am developing a PowerShell script to import an Excel file and output the data to a flat file.  The code that I have below works fine except that it fails to preserve leading zeros; when the CSV file is opened in a text editor, the leading zeros are not present.  (Leading zeros are necessary for certain ID numbers, and the ID numbers are stored in Excel using a custom format.)  Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get the ImportExcel module to preserve the leading zeros, or, perhaps another way of getting to the same goal?  I would like to do this without using the COM object and without having to install Excel on the server; that's why I've been trying to make the ImportExcel module work.

```
$dataIn = filename.xlsx ; $dataOut = filename.csv
Import-Excel -Path $dataIn | Export-Csv -Path $dataOut
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you're using the ImportExcel module?

I just did this and it worked.  I created a spreadsheet like:

```
Name         ID1          ID2
Steven  00012345     00012346
```

I gave them a custom number format of 00000000 then ran:

```
Import-Excel .\Book1.xlsx | Export-Csv .\book1.csv
```

When looking at the csv file I have both ID numbers as quoted strings:

```
"Name","ID1","ID2"
"Steven","00012345","00012346"
```

Is there anything else I need to do to reproduce this?  Can you give the specifics of the custom number format?

Also withstanding your answer to above.  You can modify the properties of each incoming object by converting them to strings.  Assuming there's a fixed number of digits you can use the string format with the .ToString() method like:

```
(12345).ToString( "00000000" )
```

This will return "00012345"...

So redoing my test with regular numbers (no custom format):

```
$Input = @(Import-Excel \\nynastech1\adm_only\ExAdm\Temp\Book1.xlsx)
$Input | 
ForEach{
    $_.ID1 = $_.ID1.ToString( "00000000" )
    $_.ID2 = $_.ID2.ToString( "00000000" )
}
```

This will convert ID1 & ID2 into "00012345" & "00012345" respectively.

You can also use Select-Object, but you might need to rename the properties.  If you are interested I can demo that approach.

Note: the @() wrapping in my example is because I only have the 1 object, and is partly force of habit.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Your first example is precisely what I am doing in my code, including the custom number format of 0000000. It is not clear to me why your example works as expected and mine does not. I'm hoping there is some local setting that may be impacting the output.  I'm going to try this on a server once I get the ImportExcel module installed there. Your second example is terrific, but would not be my first choice in this situation. The input Excel varies from-month-to-month, and there are over 240 columns. (I will give this a closer look if the first method fails.)

Comment: Totally agree, second example is basically a workaround.  I was going to suggest comparing our versions of ImportExcel.  I don't go out of my way to keep it updated, so I'm using 6.2.0 but the latest version is 6.5.3

At any rate, good luck.

Comment: I am noticing some things about the Excel file. (I will just mention that the file is from an external source and we have no control over the format.) As I mentioned earlier, the column of interest has a custom number format; however, if I click on a cell, the leading zeros are not present in the formula bar. Similar result if I change the column format to text, leading zeros disappear from the cell. This makes me think that the leading zeros are not in the data at all, but merely displayed due to the format. I may need to find a way to format the data before or after the CSV export.